# Rails 4 connect nested resource with unnested resources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

I have a site with Users (Devise, Rolify, Cancan), with Recipes and with comments for recipes.

My routes is like this:

```
resources :users

resources :recipes do
   resources :comments
end
```

My models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :recipes
has_many :comments

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :recipes
belongs_to :user
```

I am rendering the comments and the comments form on the Recipes Show action. The problem is before rendering, on the _comment.html.erb partial, when I write:

```
<%= comment.user.name %>
```

I got the undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass error.

Anyhow, I can display

```
<% comment.user_id %>
```

How do I retrieve the user name?

I have tryed:

```
<%= User.find(comment.user_id).name %>
<%= @comment.user.name %>
<%= comment.user_id.find(:name) %>
<%= comment.user_id.get(:name) %>
<%= comment.user_id(:name) %>
```

Does someone knows about full tutorial on routing? [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) I can find all the theory, but for a begginner there is a lot of holes on explanations. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) I followed up to the end, but does not explain about nested resources relation with unnested resources, and explains nothing about editing and deleting the comments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting `undefined method name' for nil:NilClass error.` means that you are setting a method `name` on NilClass. As in NilClass is an actual class in Ruby. However this is wrong. You want to set the method name on the class `User` right. So with your association set up correctly you should be able to do the following `<%= comment.user.try(:name) %>`. The purpose of try allows you to call methods on an object without it being nil meaning that if the object is empty it will not throw an error and will return Nil instead.

Comment: My User class does have a :name. And the <%= comment.user.try(:name) %> it is working perfectly. THANKS. May I make a second part of the question? How would you use <% if comment.user.avatar? %> I just tryed the try option <% if comment.user.try(:avatar) %> and, when user does not have an avatar, it does create nill class. Is there a better way to do it? Do you know a full example app on routes? Thanks again. Thanks again, you solved in one minut what took me couple of hours....

Comment: I think what you are after is doing `<%= comment.user.avatar.blank? %>` What blank does is checks if the object is blank and also can evaluate on strings which are non-empty by contain only whitespace.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong on another place because <% comment.user.avatar %> is nill with or without the blanK? It is the same problem that I had with comment.user.name, they are just not really related.

Comment: The most strange think is that it was working at the morning. The comment.user.name and the comment.user.avatar they were both working. But then I change the comments_controller and problems begun.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know what the problem was. When I first create the Comments model, after Recipe model, of course, I used rails scaffolld which generate for me a full controller with the new and edit method having each its own action view. And I did this BEFORE to associate the resources in routes.rb. So, my connections were a mess. So, when associating models, scaffold is BAD IDEA.

Correct way to do it is, generate first resource with or with out scaffold. Then forget scaffold and create second MODEL, next: associate resources, and AFTER that create second model controller. That way, connections will be rigth since the begining and, when in "recipes/show", rendering the comments and the user columns will be as easy as <%= comment.user.name %>

Thanks anyhow, David. I aprecciate the teaching.